# What are RecyclerView advantages compared to ListView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-listview

I just started using RecyclerView and I've seen it lack in a lot of features like header, footer, divider, list selector, now I have second thoughts about using it instead of ListView.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of RecyclerView compared to ListView?
Can it handle more complex views than ListView ?

I've been using ListView till now and for a few, is it time to switch to RecyclerView or is it too soon now?

Comment: all of those features are now outside the View, see http://www.grokkingandroid.com/first-glance-androids-recyclerview/